# extract string with Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

It is the very little part of HTML code, I want to get the all code wrapped by < ? and ? >.

Simply, I just want to extract the string given below.
for example,

```
   var code='<td>Total Response Sets</td><? if(byExposure) { ?><td style="text-align:right;padding-right:10px"><?= question.totals["control"] ?></td>';

  // how to extract the required code with regular expression ?
```

After using npinti, I used below code, It gives me first expression between <% & %>. But How do I get next few expressions?

```
var patt=/<\?\s*(.*?)\s*\?>/g;
var result=patt.exec(code);
console.log(result[1]);  // o/p -> if(byExposure) {
```

(For more info, Code is used for templating in underscore.js)

Comment: Where did you get the string from and why does it contain PHP?

Comment: @Felix, Hi Felix, It is just template in underscore.js. The HTML file is so huge, question popped up in mind. Can I extract the template only??        http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Comment: Ah sorry, guess I should have read the last sentence ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex:

```
<\?\s*(.*?)\s*\?>
```

Should match what you need. From the given string it matches the following:

```
<? if(byExposure) { ?>

<?= question.totals["control"] ?>
```

You can then extract the content between your markers using groups. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex) previous SO thread to see how it can be done.

This should get the job done:

```
var code='<td>Total Response Sets</td><? if(byExposure) { ?><td style="text-align:right;padding-right:10px"><?= question.totals["control"] ?></td>';
var patt=/<\?\s*(.*?)\s*\?>/g;
var result=patt.exec(code);

while (result != null) {
    alert(result[1]);
    result = patt.exec(code);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated question with your answer, It returns first expression, any idea to get next similar expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `exec`, use the `match` method:

```
res = code.match(patt);
```

**output:**

```
["<? if(byExposure) { ?>", "<?= question.totals["control"] ?>"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to extract. Do you need just the first string between <? and ?> then you can use:

```
(/<\?(.*?)\?>/.exec( code ))[1]
```

This will return **if(byExposure) {**. If you want to match between the first <? and the last ?>, then you can use:

```
(/<\?(.*?)\?>/.exec( code ))[1]
```

Comment: Your code gives only first expression between <% and %>. I wanted array of all such expressions. Thanks for your code :)